# Rotating an image

Tags: android, animation, rotation

I have two images and an imageview in android. I have set Image1 to the imageView. Now I want to rotate the image for 180 degrees when the ImageView is clicked.At the end of the rotation,I want to set image2 to the ImageView. The reverse should occur when the ImageView is clicked with image2 displayed. i.e image2 should rotate 180 degrees anti-clockwise and then image1 should be set. 
I already have the animation files for both clockwise and ant-clockwise. 
For clockwise display, the animation file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromdegrees="0"
    android:pivotx="50%"
    android:pivoty="50%"
    android:todegrees="180"
    android:toyscale="0.0" />
</set>
```

For anti-clockwise:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromdegrees="0"
        android:pivotx="50%"
        android:pivoty="50%"
        android:todegrees="-180"
        android:toyscale="0.0" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Android developer guidelines, it describes how to use the animations you defined in your XML file. Try this link [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html)